What's the deal with starting words with a-?
A lot of words seem to exist, both in English and in Spanish (and possibly in other languages which I don't know), that start with the prefix 'a-.' This prefix generally seems to imply that the word focuses on an object, rather than a subject (adónde, assimilate). However, it's not always clear to me why this form was chosen over others.
For example, the word 'annotate.' Why was the 'an-' prefix added, when just 'notate' could have been used? In fact, 'notate' (although rarely used) seems to have almost the same definition.
Additionally, it has a different origin from other a- words, such as amoral, where the Greek 'a-' is used as 'not.' Where did this form of the prefix originate, and why does it have the same meaning across multiple languages?

Different languages do different things. I would look up the use of "a" in both languages before posting...

You’re talking about two different prefixes here. One is Latin ad- ‘to, towards’, where the d assimilates to following consonants in various ways; the other is Greek ἀ-, which comes from Indo-European n̥-. The latter is called the ‘privative’ prefix; it’s cognate with, and means the same as, Latin in- (where the n assimilates like the d in ad-) and English un-.

generally questions of etymology (in this case of two morphemes) are off-topic here unless they demonstrate that there is a reasonable assumption of systematicity. In this case that's somewhat tricky to do, but demonstrating that you have looked up the etymologies of these words somewhere else would definitely help, as then an on-topic question could be framed around clearing up lingering confusion

There are a couple different prefixes being used here.
One is known as the privative prefix, which appears in a lot of different Indo-European languages. Back in Proto-Indo-European, its form was something like *n̥-, just an "n" on its own with no vowels around it. But many of the descendant languages didn't allow consonants on their own like this, so in Latin it became in- ("inaccessible"), and in English it became "un-" ("unholy"). And in Greek, the end result was an- before a vowel ("anaerobic", "anaemia") and a- before a consonant ("amoral", "asymptomatic").
Since a lot of languages (including English) like to use Greek words for technical terms, this prefix shows up a lot in science and medicine.
Another is Latin ad-, literally meaning "to". But Latin didn't allow just any consonants next to each other, so when ad- appeared before a different consonant, the D would often assimilate, becoming more like the consonant after it—which is why we say "assimilate" instead of **"adsimilate"! (This is also why we say "illogical" and "irreparable" instead of **"inlogical" and **"inreparable".)
The prefix literally meant "to", but in Latin, these verb prefixes could also be used for emphasis as well as their literal meaning. So sometimes verbs starting with ad- don't have any "to" in them; they're just more emphatic than the versions without.
And of course, Spanish is directly descended from Latin, while English got a whole lot of Latinate vocabulary from Norman French, so it makes sense that both of these languages would show these prefixes.

Do we have a word for the idea of a word (like "assimilate") demonstrating the linguistic property it describes on itself? :P

@LjL I actually don't know of one, but I try to bring these up in lectures whenever I can as mnemonics—someday I hope the term for deleting a repeated syllable will officially become "haplogy".

it's slightly different, but autological (words that describe themselves are autological, whereas here we're talking about words for a process that has occurred in that word, which is half a step removed imo) seems the closest term I can think of

@Tristan And then there's the opposite, where "loanword" is calqued from German Leinwort and "calque" is a loanword from French…antiautological?
